# Route is not working in laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

I have a searching option in index page with datatable when I search a name it filters some details and shows into the table when I click show icon in the datatable it should redirect into show.index page but it throws an error like this.but it's working on the index page but not on searching within the index page

[image]

**index page**

```
@include('theme.header')
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#search').on('click', function () {
            $value = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '{{\Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::to('search')}}',
                data: {'search': $value},
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#edpinfo').html(data);

                }
            })

        })
    })
</script>
<script>
    $.ajaxSetup({headers: {'csrftoken': '{{ csrf_token() }}'}});
</script>


<br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card m-b-30">
            <div class="card-body">

                <h4 class="mt-0 header-title">Indents</h4>

                <input type="text" id="search" class="pull-right form-rounded">
                <a href="{{route('edp')}}">
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-left">Back</button>
                </a>
                <label class="pull-right">search</label>

                <br>
                <br><br>
                <table id="datatable" class="table table-bordered  table-responsive-lg">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Slno</th>
                        <th>Customer Name</th>
                        <th>Customer Phone Number</th>
                        <th>DateOfDelivery</th>
                        <th>Delivery At</th>
                        <th>Show</th>

                    </tr>
                    </thead>


                    <tbody id="edpinfo">
                    @foreach($indents as $indent)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{$loop->iteration}}</td>
                            <td>{{$indent->customer_name}}</td>
                            <td>{{$indent->phone_no}}</td>
                            <td>{{$indent->date_of_delivery}}</td>
                            <td>{{$indent->delivery_at}}</td>
                            <td><a href="{{route('edp.show',$indent->id)}}"><img src="assets/images/select.jpg"
                                                                                 class="imgsize"></a></td>

                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- end col -->
</div> <!-- end row -->


@include('theme.footer')
```

**Controller with search Function**

```
 public function search(Request $request)
    {

        if ($request->ajax()) {

            $output = "";
            $indents = DB::table('indents')
                ->where('id', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->search . '%')
                ->orwhere('customer_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->search . '%')
                ->get();
            foreach ($indents as $key => $indent) {

                        $output .= '<tr>' .
                        '<td>' . $indent->id . '</td>' .
                        '<td>' . $indent->customer_name . '</td>' .
                        '<td>' . $indent->phone_no . '</td>' .
                        '<td>' . $indent->date_of_delivery . '</td>' .
                        '<td>' . $indent->delivery_at . '</td>' .
                       '<td>'.'.<a href="{{route(\'edp.show\',$indent->id)}}">.'.'<img src="assets/images/select.jpg" class="imgsize">.'.'</a>.'.'</td>'.
                        '</tr>';


            }
            return Response($output);
        }

    }
```

**Route File**

```
Route::get('edp', 'EdpController@index')->name('edp');
Route::get('edp/cancel/{id}', 'EdpController@cancel')->name('edp.cancel');
Route::get('search', 'EdpController@search')->name('search');
```

Specifically problem is in controller on search function routing

```
 '<td>'.'.<a href="{{route(\'edp.show\',$indent->id)}}">.'.'<img src="assets/images/select.jpg" class="imgsize">.'.'</a>.'.'</td>'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check your url is not correct in anchor tag . I think you need to change

```
'<td>'.'.<a href="{{route(\'edp.show\',$indent->id)}}">.'.'<img src="assets/images/select.jpg" class="imgsize">.'.'</a>.'.'</td>'.
```

to

```
'<td>'.'.<a href="'.route('edp.show',$indent->id).'">.'.'<img src="assets/images/select.jpg" class="imgsize">.'.'</a>.'.'</td>'.
```

Also i think there is not name route edp.show, that should also be route('edp',$indent->id)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
'<td>'.'.<a href="'.route('edp.show',$indent->id).'">.'.'<img src="assets/images/select.jpg" class="imgsize">.'.'</a>.'.'</td>'.
```

It is because you are using {{ }} in your controller while generating the html for your table and when you set the html to your table using script, the php code is never processed on the client side in your script through ajax as the page has already been loaded.

Comment: i think you didn't understand the question,the back button is working fine i have problem in the search function where in                                        '<td>'.'.<a href="{{route(\'edp.show\',$indent->id)}}">.'.'<img src="assets/images/select.jpg" class="imgsize">.'.'</a>.'.'</td>'.

Answer (score 0):

Replace route in href with url.

```
'<td>'.'.<a href="{{url(\'edp.show\'.$indent->id)}}">.'.'<img src="assets/images/select.jpg" class="imgsize">.'.'</a>.'.'</td>'.
```

Try with this

Comment: Its not working i got it with above answered by @Sumit